# Magento 2.1.5 - Sales Order reports show missing data

Tags: sales-order, reports, magento2.1.5, order-grid

I am facing issue with order sales report its skipping some data from monthly order report, Some order dates are missing in reports but in order gird it display with same dates order

> Magento: 2.1.5
>   Php: 7.0.27
>   OS: Centos

Any one have any idea what is happening with Magento version